# probability of toys in a box

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

I have 10000 boxes containing 15000 randomly distributed toys, what is the probability that a randomly chosen box has 3 toys in it?

My attempted solution:

I wanted to maximize the entropy given by:

S = -$\Sigma_n$p(n)ln(p(n))

Subject to constraints with Lagrange multipliers. I think there should be two constraint equations, one for the normalization of $p(n)$, although I'm struggling to think of and justify the second constraint equation.

Comment: Are you determined to solve the problem by maximizing entropy with constraints? It seems that the probability distribution for toys in an individual box should follow a Poisson's distribution with an average value of 1.5 . From that you should be able to quickly calculate p(3).

Comment: Also think this is a maths question pure and simple, but you need to state the maximum box capacity.